# Displaying different message boxes count as a bad practice?

Tags: actions, best-practice, messagebox

I'm developing a mobile game. From time to time, according to the current state of the user, I'm displaying promoted message boxes. I.E

[image]

Now, I have created this message box as well:

[image]

Could this confuse the user? Would it be a better practice to use the same UI colors for all the boxes (even if they represent different actions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **maintain consistency** across the application, I would suggest you follow well-defined guideline throughout. What it means is you clearly define what your common components look like and have some visual libraries defined for the same. User would anyways notice the message while engaged with your application, and to not throw any surprises you must make use of the same color for commonly used components as far as they fall under similar context.

Comment: Thank you! I changed all the message boxes to have the same look :) regardless their purpose